# Any Python OLAP/MDX ORM engines?

Tags: python, django, orm, olap, mdx

I'm new to the MDX/OLAP and I'm wondering if there is any ORM similar like Django ORM for Python that would support OLAP.

I'm a Python/Django developer and if there would be something that would have some level of integration with Django I would be much interested in learning more about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django has some OLAP features that are nearing release.

Read http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/secrets-django-orm/

http://doughellmann.com/2007/12/30/using-raw-sql-in-django.html, also

If you have a proper star schema design in the first place, then one-dimensional results can have the following form.

```
from myapp.models import SomeFact
from collections import defaultdict

facts = SomeFact.objects.filter( dimension1__attribute=this, dimension2__attribute=that )
myAggregates = defaultdict( int )
for row in facts:
    myAggregates[row.dimension3__attribute] += row.someMeasure
```

If you want to create a two-dimensional summary, you have to do something like the following.

```
facts = SomeFact.objects.filter( dimension1__attribute=this, dimension2__attribute=that )
myAggregates = defaultdict( int )
for row in facts:
    key = ( row.dimension3__attribute, row.dimension4__attribute )
    myAggregates[key] += row.someMeasure
```

To compute multiple SUM's and COUNT's and what-not, you have to do something like this.

```
class MyAgg( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.count = 0
        self.thisSum= 0
        self.thatSum= 0

myAggregates= defaultdict( MyAgg )
for row in facts:
    myAggregates[row.dimension3__attr].count += 1
    myAggregates[row.dimension3__attr].thisSum += row.this
    myAggregates[row.dimension3__attr].thatSum += row.that
```

This -- at first blush -- seems inefficient.  You're trolling through the fact table returning lots of rows which you are then aggregating in your application.

In some cases, this may be *faster* than the RDBMS's native sum/group_by.  Why?  You're using a simple mapping, not the more complex sort-based grouping operation that the RDBMS often has to use for this.  Yes, you're getting a lot of rows; but you're doing less to get them.

This has the disadvantage that it's not so declarative as we'd like.  It has the advantage that it's pure Django ORM.

Comment: I wonder how this would be updated to take advantage to Djangos recently included support to multiple databases:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Answer (score 1):

Same thing as *kpw*, I write my own stuff, except that it is exclusively for Django :

https://code.google.com/p/django-cube/

Answer (score 1):

There is also http://cubes.databrewery.org/ . Lightweight OLAP engine in python.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need - not for a full blown ORM but for a simple OLAP-like data store in Python. After coming up dry searching for existing tools I wrote this little hack:

https://github.com/kpwebb/python-cube/blob/master/src/cube.py

Even if it doesn't solve your exact need, it might be a good starting place for writing something more sophisticated.