# Django - ORM question

Tags: django, orm, date, group-by

Just wondering if it is possible to get a result that I can get using this SQL query with only Django ORM:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created, "%Y") as dte, sum(1) FROM some_table GROUP BY dte) as analytics;
```

The result is:

```
+------+--------+
| dte  | sum(1) |
+------+--------+
| 2006 |     20 | 
| 2007 |   2230 | 
| 2008 |   4929 | 
| 2009 |   1177 | 
+------+--------+
```

The simplified model looks like this:

```
# some/models.py

class Table(models.Model):
   created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

I've tried various ways using mix of .extra(select={}) and .values() and also using the .query.group_by trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469200/any-python-olap-mdx-orm-engines) but would appreciate a fresh eyes on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Django 1.1 (trunk at the time of posting this) has [aggregates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/), these allow you to perform [counts](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id9), [mins](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#min), [sums](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum), [averages](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#avg), etc. in your queries.

What you're looking to do would probably be accomplished using multiple querysets.  Remember, each row in a table (even a generated results table) is supposed to be a new object.  You don't really explain what you're summing so I'll consider it `dollars`:

```
book_years = Books.object.all().order_by('year').distinct()

# I use a list comprehension to filter out just the years
for year in [book_year.created.year for book_year in book_years]:
    sum_for_year = Book.objects.filter(created__year=year).aggregate(Sum(sales))
```

Comment: Again, I'm well aware of aggregation capabilities Django has in latest version. Could you try to build such query that does what the raw SQL I've provided does? :)

Answer (score 2):

When you need a query that Django doesn't let you express through the ORM, you can always [use raw SQL](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#topics-db-sql).

For your immediate purpose, I'm thinking that grouping by an expression (and doing an aggregate calculation on the group) is beyond Django's current capabilities.

Comment: Yes I'm well aware that I can do raw SQL, the question was can I do it with the current capabilities of ORM itself.

Comment: I'd love to learn otherwise, but I think the answer at the moment is 'No'.